# dotnetcore dns names with dotnet run

Tags: .net-core, kestrel-http-server, dotnet-cli

We have .net46 application that needs to respond to multiple hostnames e.g. `localhost.siteA.com`, `localhost.siteB.com`. This is important for us because `siteA` and `siteB` are parsed by our code. What we do is:

- Point IIS on our developer machine to the web project folder
- Edit our hosts file to forward all of these names to localhost.

This is nice because we can make code changes, build, and instantly see our results by navigating to `localhost.{site}.com`

Now we are trying to develop an application in dotnetcore2 and we need a nice development workflow.

We use the dotnet watch tools and usually run apps like so

`dotnet watch run --launch-profile test`

This way we can make changes and have the watcher pick them up. This gives us a similar workflow to the one described above for the legacy .net framework.

The problem is we need to be able to use multiple dns names when we do this. Is there a way to make it so that we can specify a hosts file of some sort so that we can still use `localhost.{site_variable}.com` to access our site?

I realize that in production we use IIS as a revere-proxy and we can setup all the bindings there. But we need a nice way to develop locally. We can't just host the app in IIS for dotnet core... because we would have to publish every time we make a change. We would like to integrate this somehow with `dotnet watch run` workflow.